# Set text table hsqldb java exception

Tags: java, database, file, exception, hsqldb

I have a matrix save in a txt file and I want to load it into an hsqldb table where each column in the matrix is loaded into a column in the table.

This is what I did

```
kId= new String[numOfFields];
        String f="";
        String ff="";
        String fff="";
            for (int i=0;i<kId.length;i++) {
                while(rss.next())   
                {
                kId[i]=rss.getString(1);
                f="a"+kId[i]+ " varchar(7)";
                ff+="a"+kId[i]+", ";
                fff+="a"+kId[i]+ " varchar(7), ";
                String sqlalter=new String("ALTER TABLE "+ tableName +" add "+f+"");
                //System.out.println(sqlalter);
                stmt1.executeUpdate(sqlalter);
            }

        }
            f=f.substring(0, f.length()-1);
            ff = ff.replaceAll(", $","");
            fff = fff.replaceAll(", $","");

        String sqlmatrixcreate=new String ("CREATE TEXT TABLE tempMatrixTable " + " ("+fff+") ");
        //System.out.print(sqlmatrixcreate);
        stmt1.executeUpdate(sqlmatrixcreate);
        String setTempMatrixTable= new String ("set table "+"tempMatrixTable"+ " ("+ff+") " + " source 'matrix.txt'");
        stmt1.executeUpdate( setTempMatrixTable);
        String insertWeight=  new String("INSERT INTO "+ tableName +"("+ff+")"+ " select weight from tempMatrixTable");
        System.out.print(insertWeight);
        stmt1.executeUpdate(insertWeight);
        String dropTempWeight= new String("drop table tempMatrixTable");
        //stmt1.executeUpdate(dropTempKey);
```

The structure of tableName is as follow
ID | a1 | a2 | a3 .... and so on

The structure of tempMatrixTable is as follow
a1 | a2 | a3 .... and so on

When I run this code I got this exception

```
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: (   --> It refers to the line to execute the set statement
```

Please guide me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be an open parenthesis after the name of the table:

```
String setTempMatrixTable= new String ("set table "+"tempMatrixTable"+ " source 'matrix.txt'");
```